# Null exception on inserting object to SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

Im creating a very basic fragment containing 2 EditText fields and a submit button.
On submit the values should be inserted as a row to my SQLite DB.
Im getting a NullPointerException i just dont get..

Inside my onCreateView method of the fragment im getting my field values and setting up a click listener like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_customer, container, false);
    customerName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editCompanyName);
    customerAddress = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editCompanyAddress);
    addButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submitCustomerBtn);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String sCustomerName = customerName.getText().toString();
            String sCustomerAddress = customerAddress.getText().toString();
            if(sCustomerName.trim().length() > 0 && sCustomerAddress.trim().length() > 0) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setName(sCustomerName);
                customer.setAddress(sCustomerAddress);
                customer.setLocation("Not set");
                customer.setImage("None");
                customer = dataSource.createCustomer(customer);
                if(customer.getId() != 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), customer.getName() + " with id: " + customer.getId() + " was created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Customer created with id " + customer.getId());
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
```

Inside my dataSource class where i controle my DB query and statement im calling the createCustomer method, which looks like this:

```
public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BusinessDBOpenHelper.CUSTOMER_NAME, customer.getName());
    values.put(BusinessDBOpenHelper.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, customer.getAddress());
    values.put(BusinessDBOpenHelper.CUSTOMER_LOCATION, customer.getLocation());
    values.put(BusinessDBOpenHelper.CUSTOMER_IMAGE, customer.getImage());
    long insertid = database.insert(BusinessDBOpenHelper.TABLE_CUSTOMER, null, values);
    customer.setId(insertid);
    return customer;
}
```

My Customer model is also just containg long id, String name, String address, String location, String image with getters and setters..
The null exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.example.app.model.Customer org.example.app.db.BusinessDataSource.createCustomer(org.example.app.model.Customer)' on a null object reference
        at org.example.app.AddCustomerFragment$1.onClick(Fragment.java:55)
```

Comment: where do you initialize dataSource, maybe its null

Comment: AHHH! jesus, ofcourse. I think thats it - looking now

Comment: glad you got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
dataSource.createCustomer(customer);
```

is null, you have to initialize

```
dataSource
```

somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The error stacks says your are calling createCustomer on a null `dataSource`.

where do you initialize it? Find it and make sure it is not null when `onClick()` is called.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.example.app.model.Customer
 org.example.app.db.BusinessDataSource.createCustomer(org.example.app.model.Customer)'
 on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found one issue. I will try to explain in detail if someone else need it:

First of all you have to check if your object 'dataSource' is typed = SQLiteDatabase, just like that :

`private SQLiteDatabase dataSource;`

and initialize your object before use it, like that :

`dataSource = this.getWritableDatabase();`